# CSVファイルのidentically-labeled エラーの解決方法は？

Tags: python, csv

**やりたいこと**
2つのcsvファイルを比較して、両ファイル内の差分を抽出し別のファイルにデータを書き込みたいですが、
下記のエラーが発生します。indexエラーだと思われます。

**csvデータ① (A,B,Cカンマ区切り)**

```
A  B      C  
1 アメリカ   ○
2 カナダ　　×
3 日本     △
4 イタリア　 ○
5 イギリス　 □
6 メキシコ  空白
7　空白　　空白
８　空白    　□
9  チリ    ○
```

**csvデータ② (A,B,Cカンマ区切り)**

```
A  B      C  
1 アメリカ   ○
2 カナダ　　□　→”×”→”□”変わった部分ですが、”□”は除外
3 日本     ○ →”△”→”○”変わった部分
4 イタリア　 ○ 
5 イギリス　 ×→”□”→”✖️”変わった部分
6 メキシコ　空白
7　空白　　空白
```

抽出したいデータは”○”と”✖️”で変わった時と追加された行です。
＊ヘッダ付きと改行されている形式で下記のように表示したいです。

```
A  B      C  
3 日本     ○
5 イギリス　 ×
9  チリ    ○
```

こちらのコードを記載しましたが下記のように表示されます。

```
import csv
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.read_csv('test1.csv',encoding='utf_8_sig')
df2 = pd.read_csv('test2.csv',encoding='utf_8_sig')

#ファイルの比較
df3 = df2.iloc[df1.compare(df2).sort_index(inplace=True)]

#特定の文字を検索
df_h = df3[df3["C"].str.contains("○|✖️",na=False)]

#Csvファイル書き込み
df_h.to_csv("test.csv",encoding='utf_8_sig',index=False)
```

**エラー内容**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:/Users/test/Documents/compare.py", line 5, in <module>
    df3 = df2.iloc[df1.compare(df2).index]
  File "C:\Users\test\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 5995, in compare
    return super().compare(
  File "C:\Users\test\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py", line 8398, in compare
    mask = ~((self == other) | (self.isna() & other.isna()))
  File "C:\Users\test\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\ops\__init__.py", line 705, in f
    self, other = _align_method_FRAME(self, other, axis, level=None, flex=False)
  File "C:\Users\test\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\ops\__init__.py", line 510, in _align_method_FRAME
    raise ValueError(
ValueError: Can only compare identically-labeled DataFrame objects
```

わかる方いらっしゃいましたらご教示願います。
お手数ですが、宜しくお願いいたします。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`df1` と `df2` は行数が異なるので当該のエラーが発生しています。ですので `df1` の行を切り詰めて `df2` と比較した後、その結果と `df1` の残りの部分を結合します。

```py
import csv
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.read_csv('test1.csv',encoding='utf_8_sig')
df2 = pd.read_csv('test2.csv',encoding='utf_8_sig')

df3 = pd.concat([df2.iloc[df2.compare(df1[:len(df2)]).index], df1[len(df2):]])
df_h = df3[df3["C"].str.contains("○|×",na=False)].reset_index(drop=True)
df_h.to_csv("test.csv",encoding='utf_8_sig',index=False)

pd.set_option('display.unicode.east_asian_width', True)
print(df_h)
=>
   A         B  C
0  3       日本  ○
1  5    イギリス　×
2  9       チリ  ○
```

Comment: こちらで問題なく実行出来ました。ありがとうございます。